# Find first available identifier from database table

Tags: php, mysql, unique, identifier, alphanumeric

The requirement is to find the first available identifier where an identifier is an alphanumeric string, such as:

```
ABC10000
ABC10345
ABC88942
ABC90123
```

The database table has a structure such as:

```
id, user, identifier
```

Note that the alpha component `ABC` is consistent throughout and won't change. The numeric component should be between 10000 and 99999.

How best to tackle this? It does not seem like an overly complex problem - looking for simplest solution using either just MySQL or a combination of SQL and PHP. The current solution pulls each record from the database into an array and then loops from 10000 onwards, prepending `ABC` and checking availability, which seems like it could be improved significantly.

---

Edit: Original question was not clear enough in that a certain amount of identifiers have been assigned already, and I am looking to fill in the gaps. From the short list I provided, the next available would be ABC10001. Eventually, however, it would be ABC10346 and then ABC88943 and so on

---

Edit: Sorry for a poorly structured question. To avoid any further confusion, here is the actual table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User_Loc` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_64FB41DA17323CBC` (`user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4028 ;
```

Comment: Will it be always last record? Or its posible that you will have free id between values i.e. abc10000, abc10002 and you need 10001 ?

Comment: Thanks - I have clarified above. It is to be the first available "missing" identifier.

Comment: @HerrSerker - that is a bad comment. Perhaps identifier was a poor choice to use (in fact, the field name is `value`). If you would care to elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to self join the table and look for the first NULL value in the joined table

```
SELECT CONCAT('ABC', SUBSTRING(t1.value, 4)+1) AS next_value
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 on SUBSTRING(t1.value, 4)+1 = SUBSTRING(t2.value, 4)
WHERE ISNULL(t2.value)
ORDER BY t1.value ASC
LIMIT 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d69105/22

---

### edit

With the comment about some 'specialities' at ncatnow. There are slight adjusments to make with the help of subselects for ridding the `'ABC'` and `UNION` for having a default value

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('ABC', t1.value+1) AS next_value

FROM 
((SELECT '09999' AS value) UNION (SELECT SUBSTRING(value, 4) AS value FROM test)) t1
LEFT JOIN 
((SELECT '09999' AS value) UNION (SELECT SUBSTRING(value, 4) AS value FROM test)) t2 
  ON t1.value+1 = t2.value

WHERE 
  ISNULL(t2.value) 
  AND t1.value >= '09999'

ORDER BY t1.value ASC
LIMIT 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28acf6/50

Comment: This seems pretty close but is not returning the correct result - I'm getting `ABC1`. It is using the primary key rather than the `identifier` field. This fiddle represents the problem better: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d69105/1

Comment: @ncatnow I don't know about the exact structure of your table, so I made an example. You have to adopt this to your needs.

Comment: The minor issue is that if you have ABC0000 it will chop off the ABC to get 00000, and think that will be cast to an integer 0 when added to, resulting in 1, which is then concatenated on GIVING ABC1.

Comment: @Kickstart That's true, but the OP did say, the identifier numeral does not start with zeros.

Comment: @HerrSerker - it doesn't work. See this fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d69105/2. It should return ABC10002. It would seem the reason it does not work is explained by Kickstart

Comment: No, the issue is that it is adding 1 to the id, not the identifier (ie, the value column in your sqlfiddle). Easy fix.

Comment: Thanks for your perseverance, I will accept your answer if you could update it to use the correct field. Cheers!

Comment: @HerrSerker - I've noticed this relies on an initial record with value of ABC10000. There were two problems when applying to the actual data set, neither of which I mentioned initially:

- there is a "special" record of ABC00000
- the next record is ABC15800

I've skipped ABC00000 by enforcing `SUBSTRING(m1.value, 4) > 9999`, and adding a ABC10000 record ensures it grabs ABC10001. I thought you might be interested to know, here is the latest fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd269/1. As you can see, it returns ABC10306 but should return ABC10000. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the above reply by @HerrSerker, but this will cope with existing identifiers which have the numeric part starting with a zero.

```
SELECT CONCAT('ABC',SUBSTRING(CONCAT('00000', CAST((CAST(SUBSTRING(a.identifier, 4) AS SIGNED) + 1) AS CHAR)), -5)) AS NextVal
FROM SomeTable a
LEFT OUTER JOIN SomeTable b
ON b.identifier = CONCAT('ABC',SUBSTRING(CONCAT('00000', CAST((CAST(SUBSTRING(a.identifier, 4) AS SIGNED) + 1) AS CHAR)), -5))
WHERE b.identifier IS NULL
ORDER BY NextVal
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'm getting `#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='`

Comment: Might need to see your table declares for this, but you possibly need to force the collation on the join.

Comment: Forced collation on the join - it returned back ABC00001. Getting close!

Comment: Tried it on your SQL fiddle (even without forcing collation, just changing the column name and table name to match) and it returned ABC10002. Strange

Comment: If you care to post the link, I'll take a look - I've probably done something wrong.

Comment: @Kickstart Better use `LPAD()` instead of your `SUBSTRING(..., -5)` construct

Comment: @HerrSerker - good suggestion. Used the SUBSTRING way of doing it for too long in too many languages and didn't think of using lpad

Answer (score 0):

what comes to my mind is one table with all indentifiers and use this sql

```
SELECT identifier FROM allIdentifiersTable WHERE identifier NOT IN (SELECT identifier FROM yourTable) LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Reconsidering this from your edit, you should go the PHP route and add another table or other means to store the last filled id:

```
$identifier = 0;
$i = mysql_query("SELECT identifier FROM last_identifier");
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($i)) $identifier = $row["identifier"];
if ($identifier < 10000) $identifier = 10000;

do {
    $identifier += 1;
    $result = mysql_query("
         INSERT IGNORE INTO table (id, user, identifier)
         VALUES ('[...]', '[...]',
         'ABC" . str_pad($identifier, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "'
    )");
    if (mysql_affected_rows($result) < 1) continue;
} while (false);

mysql_query("UPDATE last_identifier SET identifier = '$identifier'");
```

Of course, you need to add a `UNIQUE` index on the identifier field.

Comment: The `id` field is autoincrement and it actually goes up by 4 each time  - apparently to aid in replication but that is beside the point. 

Your answer is interesting - but I don't agree with using the record id for this. The table structure is not to change - my question is how to find the missing identifiers using the current structure, data and limitations.